# How exactly does Encapsulation via Data Hiding Work in Python? Beginner

Tags: python, polymorphism, encapsulation

I'm covering a section of Python on Class Polymorphism, specifically Encapsulation and Data Hiding.

The Example of such an Encapsulation is:

```
class Car:

    __maxspeed = 0
    __name = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.__maxspeed = 200
        self.__name = "Corolla"

    def drive(self):
        print("Max speed is: " + str(self.__maxspeed))

    def setMaxSpeed(self,speed):
        self.__maxspeed = speed

car_a = Car()
car_a.drive()
car_a.setMaxSpeed(320)
car_a.drive()
```

The line `car_a.drive()` leads us to `print("Max speed is: " + str(self.__maxspeed))`. Where does the value for this specific `self__maxspeed` come from and why?

From the output, I see it's 200. And the output of `car_a.setMaxSpeed(320)` is 320. So the same question here with 320. And lastly, what's the function of `__maxspeed = 0` and `__nane = ""`?

Sorry for the extensive question. I new to Python and these examples confused me. I greatly appreciate all help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where does the value (200) for this specific self__maxspeed come from and
>   why?

It comes from the `__init__` method, which is invoked when you call `Car()`:

```
self.__maxspeed = 200
```

Any time you create a `Car` it will have a `maxspeed` of 200 until you set it to something else.

> And the output of car_a.setMaxSpeed(320) is 320. So the same question
>   here with 320.

Here's the `setMaxSpeed` function:

```
def setMaxSpeed(self,speed):
    self.__maxspeed = speed
```

As you can see, it takes whatever you pass as the argument (320) and sets `self.__maxspeed` to it.  Nothing too mysterious about it.  That `Car` will now have a `maxspeed` of 320 until you set it to something else.

> lastly, what's the function of __maxspeed = 0 and __name = ""

They don't have any function.  That is to say, your code never uses them for anything, so either their presence is a mistake, or you have some other code that does something with them, but based on the code you've presented, they are useless and you could delete them with no ill effects.

Comment: `car_a.__maxspeed = 10 # will not change variable because its Private`
This is a line in the previous example that isn't supposed to work.

Comment: This all just clicked. I was overthinking it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`__init__()` is invoked everytime whenever any object is created.

After creating the object, the `__init__()` is invoked automatically.

In this case, `__init__()` is initializing 
`__maxspeed` with value of *200* . Then, you printed the value of `__maxspeed` (which is *200* ) using `drive()` function .

Later, you invoked `setMaxSpeed()` with *320* as a value. Inside this function, it assigned 320 to the `__maxspeed` variable of that object which has *200* as it's initial value.

Now, you again invoked `drive()` function to print the value of `__maxspeed` which is now *320* . So, *320* is printed.